# How to trigger Maven SCM plugin to automatically switch goals based on existing directory?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-scm

I'm new to Maven and having an issue where I'm trying to automatically change the SCM plugin goal from `checkout` to **update** based on whether the source is already checked out.

Can anyone show me a code example to get this working?
This is the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>checkout</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <connectionType>developerConnection</connectionType>
                    <scmVersion>master</scmVersion>
                    <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
                    <checkoutDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</checkoutDirectory>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `goal`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>update</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <connectionType>developerConnection</connectionType>
                    <scmVersion>master</scmVersion>
                    <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
                    <checkoutDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</checkoutDirectory>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Reference**
https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/ 
https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/update-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks Do, Update fails if the project is not bootstrapped using checkout. How does this automatically switch between checkout and update based on whether the checkout is complete ? I clarified the question.

Comment: This link maybe helpful for you: https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/examples/bootstrapping-with-pom.html

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to switch automatically.  I edited the question to clarify

Comment: Give this solution  a chance to try: set property like default value `skipCheckoutIfExists = false`
https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html#skipCheckoutIfExists

Comment: Awesome, This looks like it will work... let me try a few other options using a profile. brb

Comment: Do, sorry for the delay, got caught up on a call. Thanks to your suggestions, I was able to develop a profile based approach. I'm not too happy with the 'missing' tag requiring a, actual path instead of a property, but it works..

Answer (score 0):

To change the goal of the SCM plugin was inspired by  Đỗ Như Vý (above).

Approach was to

1. Place the goal in a property called scm.goal set to a default value
   ie update.
2. Use a profile (bootstrap) to change the  scm.goal property value from
   'update' to 'checkout'.
3. Activate the bootstrap profile based on missing .gitignore file.
4. Place the property scm.goal in the SCM plugin
   goal element.

Code:

```
    <properties>
        <scm.dest.path>${project.basedir}/src</scm.dest.path>
        <scm.goal>update</scm.goal>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile> 
            <id>bootstrap</id> 
            <activation> 
                <file>
                  <missing>./src/.gitignore</missing>
                </file>
             </activation> 
            <properties>
                <scm.goal>checkout</scm.goal>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>${scm.goal}</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <connectionType>developerConnection</connectionType>
                            <scmVersion>master</scmVersion>
                            <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
                            <checkoutDirectory>${scm.dest.path}</checkoutDirectory>
                            <workingDirectory>${scm.dest.path}</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
...
```